Can't catch an error with on error operator
Sub TextToNum()
  Dim af As Double
  For Each x In Selection
    On Error GoTo 10
    af = x.Value 'here appears error
    x.NumberFormat = Number
    On Error GoTo -1
    x.Value = af
  10 Next x
End Sub

If the value of the cell can't be converted to number, (letters, symbols), then there appears the error message and macros stops executing. Pass this error via On Error fails, -the error message appears any way. How to solve this?

This question is similar to: Error handling only works once. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Step through it with a debugger - I believe your code will handle the first one properly, but not the second.

You can use IsNumeric instead of error checking:
Sub TextToNum()
Dim af As Double
Dim x As Range
For Each x In Selection
    If IsNumeric(x.Value) Then
        af = x.Value
        x.NumberFormat = Number
        x.Value = af
    End If
Next x
End Sub


